# After a problematic software update OS boots only with SELinux disabled

Tags: fedora, boot, selinux, software-updates

I have Fedora 38.

The last software update messed up my system. It became unbootable. The reason probably was in having duplicate packages. I managed to fix `dnf check` errors by `dnf remove --duplicates` and `dnf distro-sync`.

After this the only error I had was `[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems.` Which I "fixed" by disabling SELinux.

I'm not competent enough in this, so I would like to know why the system now only boots up with the SELinux disabled. And how can I fix it so I can enable it back?

Comment: Try `touch /.autorelabel` and then rebooting and see if that resolves your problem -- that forces a complete relabeling of the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, it did. But the SELinux should be in the permissive mode. Seems obvious, but not when you don't know what you are doing :) All good now, it relabelled the files and now boots up normally with SELinux in the enforcing mode.

Answer (score 1):

How it was fixed:

1. Boot using a live usb
2. chroot into the root partition
3. Disable SELinux updating the `/etc/selinux/config` file
4. Boot normally
5. Do `touch /.autorelabel`
6. Set SELinux into permissive mode in `/etc/selinux/config`
7. Reboot and wait till the relabelling is finished
8. Boot normally and now set SELinux back into enforcing mode in `/etc/selinux/config`

Now it should boot with no issues.

Steps 5 and 6 probably can be done instead of step 2.